# read.xlsx and colClasses

Tags: r, r-xlsx

Does anyone know why argument `colClasses` does not seem to work in `read.xlsx`?

I create a sample *.xlsx file:

```
> library(xlsx)
> d1 = data.frame(A=LETTERS[1:3], B=letters[1:3], C=1:3, D=c(1.1, NA, NA))
> str(d1)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ A: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
 $ B: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3
 $ C: int  1 2 3
 $ D: num  1.1 NA NA
> write.xlsx(d1, 'test.xlsx', sheetName='Sheet1', row.names=F, showNA=F)
```

then try to read it with `read.xlsx`, without and with `colClasses` argument:

```
> d2 = read.xlsx('test.xlsx', sheetName='Sheet1')
> str(d2)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ A: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
 $ B: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3
 $ C: num  1 2 3
 $ D: num  1.1 NA NA
> d2 = read.xlsx('test.xlsx', sheetName='Sheet1', colClasses=c(B='character', 'A'='character'))
> str(d2)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ A: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
 $ B: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3
 $ C: num  1 2 3
 $ D: num  1.1 NA NA
```

The problem is `colClasses` seems to have no effect. Any  ideas?

Thank you for your help.

Aleksey

P.S. I have R 3.0.1, `xlsx` 0.5.1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`colClasses=` is working but the problem is that on your system default action when import data is to convert character columns to factor.

If you import `test.xlsx` and set that all columns should be `"character"`, you see that all columns are made as factors (also numbers).

```
d2 = read.xlsx('test.xlsx', sheetName='Sheet1', colClasses=rep("character",4))
 str(d2)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ A: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
 $ B: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3
 $ C: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3
 $ D: Factor w/ 1 level "1.1": 1 NA NA
```

To ensure that characters are not converted to factors you can add argument `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to function `read.xlsx()`.

```
d2 = read.xlsx('test.xlsx', sheetName='Sheet1', 
                colClasses=c(B='character', A='character'),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

str(d2)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ A: chr  "A" "B" "C"
 $ B: chr  "a" "b" "c"
 $ C: num  1 2 3
 $ D: num  1.1 NA NA
```

Comment: Didzis, thank you, this works great. I forgot that `stringsAsFactors` does the second pass conversion, casting character vectors as factors. Thank you, and sorry for forgetting about this question for so long.

Comment: @Didzis Elferts, `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` does not work with `read.xlsx`. I am not sure if it is related to its version. I am using `openxlsx` version `4.2.5`.